# Python - "in" statement search slow for list of objects

Tags: python, list, search, python-2.7

I'm hoping someone can explain why searching a list of object references is so much slower than searching a normal list. This is using the python "in" keyword to search which I thought runs at "C compiler" speed. I thought a list is just an array of object references (pointers) so the search should be extremely fast. Both lists are exactly 412236 bytes in memory.

Normal list (takes 0.000 seconds to search):

```
alist = ['a' for x in range(100000)]
if 'b' in alist:
    print("Found")
```

List of object references (takes 0.469 !! seconds to search):

```
class Spam:
    pass
spamlist = [Spam() for x in range(100000)]
if Spam() in spamlist:
    print("Found")
```

---

Edit: So apparently this has something to do with old-style classes having way more overhead than new style classes. My script that was bogging down with only 400 objects can now easily handle up to 10000 objects simply by making all my classes inherit from the "object" class. Just when I thought I knew Python!.
I've read about new-style vs old-style before but it was never mentioned that old-style classes can be up to 100x slower than new style ones. What is the best way to search a list of object instances for a particular instance?
1. Keep using the "in" statement but make sure all classes are new style.
2. Perform some other type of search using the "is" statement like:

```
[obj for obj in spamlist if obj is target]
```

3. Some other more Pythonic way?

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mostly due to the different special method lookup mechanics of *old-style classes*.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("Spam() in l", """
... # Old-style
... class Spam: pass
... l = [Spam() for i in xrange(100000)]""", number=10)
3.0454677856675403
>>> timeit.timeit("Spam() in l", """
... # New-style
... class Spam(object): pass
... l = [Spam() for i in xrange(100000)]""", number=10)
0.05137817007346257
>>> timeit.timeit("'a' in l", 'l = ["b" for i in xrange(100000)]', number=10)
0.03013876870841159
```

As you can see, the version where `Spam` inherits from `object` runs much faster, almost as fast as the case with strings.

The `in` operator for lists uses `==` to compare items for equality. `==` is defined to try the objects' `__eq__` methods, their `__cmp__` methods, and pointer comparison, in that order.

For old-style classes, this is implemented in a straightforward but slow manner. Python has to actually look for the `__eq__` and `__cmp__` methods in each instance's dict and the dicts of each instance's class and superclasses. `__coerce__` gets looked up too, as part of the 3-way compare process. When none of these methods actually exist, that's something like 12 dict lookups just to get to the pointer comparison. There's a bunch of other overhead besides the dict lookups, and I'm not actually sure which aspects of the process are the most time-consuming, but suffice it to say that the procedure is more expensive than it could be.

For built-in types and new-style classes, things are better. First, Python doesn't look for special methods on the instance's dict. This saves some dict lookups and enables the next part. Second, type objects have C-level function pointers corresponding to the Python-level special methods. When a special method is implemented in C or doesn't exist, the corresponding function pointer allows Python to skip the method lookup procedure entirely. This means that in the new-style case, Python can quickly detect that it should skip straight to the pointer comparison.

As for what you should do, I'd recommend using `in` and new-style classes. If you find that this operation is becoming a bottleneck, but you need old-style classes for backward compatibility, `any(x is y for y in l)` runs about 20 times faster than `x in l`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('x in l', '''
... class Foo: pass
... x = Foo(); l = [Foo()] * 100000''', number=10)
2.8618816054721936
>>> timeit.timeit('any(x is y for y in l)', '''
... class Foo: pass
... x = Foo(); l = [Foo()] * 100000''', number=10)
0.12331640524583776
```

Comment: Ok do you ve any explanation for this : Searching string from list of strings and, searching string from list of integers.                                            >>> Timer("'1' in L", "L = [str(10) for x in range(100000)]").timeit(number=1000)
1.410999059677124
>>> Timer("'1' in L", "L = [10 for x in range(100000)]").timeit(number=1000)
5.952347993850708
>>>

Comment: Changing "class Spam:" to "class Spam(object)" seems to be the fix.

Comment: @yopy Comparing the string `'1'` with the integer `10` seems to be qiite expensive - and pointless.

Comment: @yopy I just tested: your 2 tests take 3.64 resp. 10.17 s on my machine, while `timeit.Timer("1 in L", "L = [10 for x in range(100000)]").timeit(number=1000)` takes 3.15 s.

Comment: @glglgl i know its quite pointless but i was looking for its slowness. it just do the comparison till the end of the list element. because there is no string in the list.

Comment: @user2357112 I've had a look around the web and I can't find any information on this. Is this difference between new style and old style classes documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right answer for your question but this will a very good knowledge for who wants to understand how 'in' keywords works under the hood :

ceval sourcecode : [ceval.c source code](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/trunk/Python/ceval.c?revision=82177&content-type=text/plain)
abstract.c sourcecode : [abstract.c source code](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/trunk/Objects/abstract.c?content-type=text/plain)
From the mail : [mail about 'in' keywords](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-January/044460.html)

**Expalantion from the mail thread:**

I'm curious enough about this (OK, I admit it, I like to be right, too 
;) to dig in to the details, if anyone is interested...one of the 
benefits of Python being open-source is you can find out how it works...

First step, look at the bytecodes:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(x, y):
...   return x in y
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
2          0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
           3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
           6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
           9 RETURN_VALUE
```

So `in` is implemented as a `COMPARE_OP`. Looking in `ceval.c` for 
COMPARE_OP, it has some optimizations for a few fast compares, then 
calls `cmp_outcome()` which, for 'in', calls PySequence_Contains().

PySequence_Contains() is implemented in abstract.c. If the container 
implements `__contains__`, that is called, otherwise 
`_PySequence_IterSearch()` is used.

`_PySequence_IterSearch()` calls `PyObject_GetIter()` to constuct an 
iterator on the sequence, then goes into an infinite loop (for (;;)) 
calling PyIter_Next() on the iterator until the item is found or the 
call to PyIter_Next() returns an error.

`PyObject_GetIter()` is also in `abstract.c`. If the object has an 
`__iter__()` method, that is called, otherwise `PySeqIter_New()` is called 
to construct an iterator.

`PySeqIter_New()` is implemented in `iterobject.c`. It's `next()` method is in 
`iter_iternext()`. This method calls `__getitem__()` on its wrapped object 
and increments an index for next time.

So, though the details are complex, I think it is pretty fair to say 
that the implementation uses a while loop (in _PySequence_IterSearch()) 
and a counter (wrapped in PySeqIter_Type) to implement 'in' on a 
container that defines `__getitem__ but not __iter__`.

By the way the implementation of 'for' also calls PyObject_GetIter(), so 
it uses the same mechanism to generate an iterator for a sequence that 
defines `__getitem__()`.

Answer (score 0):

Python creates one immutable 'a' object and each element in a list points to the same object. Since Spam() is mutable, each instance is a different object, and dereferencing the pointers in spamlist will access many areas in RAM. The performance difference may have something to do with hardware cache hits/misses.

Obviously the performance difference would be even greater if you are including list creation time in your results (instead of just `Spam() in spamlist`. Also try `x = Spam(); x in spamlist` to see if that makes a difference.

I am curious how `any(imap(equalsFunc, spamlist))` compares.

Answer (score 0):

Using the the test of `alist = ['a' for x in range(100000)]` can be very misleading because of [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). Turns out that Python will intern (in most cases) short immutables -- especially strings -- so that they are all the same object.

Demo:

```
>>> alist=['a' for x in range(100000)]
>>> len(alist)
100000
>>> len({id(x) for x in alist})
1
```

You can see that while a list of 100000 strings is created it is only comprised of one interned object.

A more fair case would be to use a call to `object` to guarantee that each is a unique Python object:

```
>>> olist=[object() for x in range(100000)]
>>> len(olist)
100000
>>> len({id(x) for x in olist})
100000
```

If you compare the in operator with `olist` you will find the timing to be similar.

Comment: I am not sure if it will make a huge difference. If I iterate over the `alist` and I get each time the same object, the comparison will happen for each item nevertheless.